# "equally skilled as X" or "equally skilled to X"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which of the following (if either) is correct?

> I consider myself equally skilled as LeBron.
>
> I consider myself equally skilled to LeBron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, neither is recommended: you would either say *Lebron and I are equally skilled* or *I consider myself (just) as skilled as Lebron*. I believe *equally as* is used by some people, though. *Equally to* is probably less common.